# Exactly Two Suits in A Hand of $5$.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

How many $5$-card hands can be formed from an ordinary deck of $52$ cards if exactly two
suits are present in the hand?

I don't know how to solve this problem.

This is my attempt:

$\binom{4}{2}(13)(5)$.

Answer (score 1):

It is easier to choose the suits as the one that will be in the majority and the one that will be in the minority.  There are $12$ ways to choose the suits.  If you have three of one suit, there are ${13 \choose 3}$ ways to choose the cards from the majority suit, and ${13 \choose 2}$ way to choose the cards of the other suit.  The case of $4$ and $1$ is similar.