# Amount of Bridge Hands

Tags: discrete-mathematics

A bridge hand has 13 cards.

How any bridge hands can there possibly be if the hands contains exactly two suits?

I think it is a few combinations multiplied together, don't know how to set this up.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exactly Two Suits in A Hand of $5$.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/327008/exactly-two-suits-in-a-hand-of-5)  Although the linked question is of a hand of size five, the method is exactly the same when applied to a hand of size thirteen.

Comment: I have retracted my *close as duplicate* vote since in this case with the handsize being thirteen cards there is a much cleaner solution than that in the linked question above.  The method applied in the above is still good and will arrive at an answer as well but will involve more arithmetic than is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Break this into shorter, simpler questions.

Step 1:

> How many ways can you form a hand of size $13$ if the only cards that are available are the twenty six cards of $\spadesuit$ or $\heartsuit$?

We have twenty six cards available, and we want thirteen of them

> $\binom{26}{13}$

Step 2:

> In how many ways then can we have both suits present when taking a hand of thirteen cards from our twenty six $\spadesuit$ and $\heartsuit$ cards?

We don't want our hand to be entirely one suit.

> $\binom{26}{13}-2$

Step 3:

> How many ways can we select two suits out of the available four?

We have four suits available and we want to pick two of them.

> $\binom{4}{2}$

So, putting all of this together, we approach via multiplication principle

- Pick two suits
- Pick a hand of thirteen cards which uses *both* suits and only those suits

> For a final answer of $\binom{4}{2}(\binom{26}{13}-2)$

Comment: I don't understand the syntax with the "fraction-like" numbers. Is that another way to say combination? @JMoravitz

Comment: @DrakeJacks $\binom{n}{r}=~_nC_r=\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$ is the [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient).  The number of ways of selecting $r$ objects from a total of $n$ distinct objects.